# mp4 video created using direct show filter is not playing

Tags: c++, directshow, mp4

Using direct show filters I have created a mp4 file writer with two input pin (one for audio and one for video) . I was writing audio sample received through one pin into one track and video sample received from the other pin into another track. But my video is not playing. If I connected only one pin, either Audio or Video, I can play the output file. that is if there is only one track.

I am using h264 encoder for video and mpeg4 encoder for audio. The encoders are working fine as I am able to play the audio and video separately.

I am setting the track count as 2. Is there any information to be provided in the moov box to make the video playing. Or Should we tell the decoder that which track is audio and which track is video. As we are setting those fields in track information I don't think that is important, but Why my video is not playing?

Comment: It seems the problem is around producing wrong formatted file. On the outer interface you are accepting data, but you are writing something incorrectly. Since you are inspecting the file with atom viewer, you should be able to compare the structure against playable file and locate the problematic boxes.

Comment: but i dont hink i am getting any wrong box. As I told, if I am connecting only audio pin of my filter, I am able to play the audio. If only video pin is connected, the output file is able to display video. when I connect both at the same time, video is not playing. I think I am missing some sync information. I m stil searchin for some parameter that I missed to set.

Comment: You are creating the file on your own, since the streams themselves are correct - the problem has nothing to do with DirectShow itself, it is the resulting file structure that gives troubles.

Comment: yes, you are right. I was searching what is the error with the file structure, which parameter I m missing